# How to introduce line break in a string whenever keyword occurs in java?

Tags: java, replaceall

Objective: prefix each keyword with new line in a string

code snippet:

```
String [] keys = {"Status:","Active:","Priority:"};
text="Status:   Open    Active: Yes Priority:   None";
System.out.println("Before: "+text);
for(int k = 0; k<keys.length; k++){
text = text.replaceAll(keys[k], "\r\n"+keys[k]);
}
System.out.println("After: "+text);
```

Expected Output:

```
[new line]
Status: Open    
Active: Yes 
Priority:   None
```

Actual Output:

```
[new line]
Status: Open    Active: Yes Priority:   None
```

Update: the text is copied from web page with charset utf-8, pasted in notepad and saved with encoding utf-8. the text read by the program and unable to process. the same string has been pasted, I think encoding is not preserved.

Please help me resolving the issue.

Comment: [Can not reproduce!](https://onlinegdb.com/BJvCJsVYH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text contains `\r\n` but the way it is displayed does not show them.

`System.out.println` print all on a single line, and at the end, this method insert a new line character.

If you want to print out the modified text only for debug purpose, you can do this:

```
System.out.println("After: " + text.replaceAll("\r\n", "\\r\\n");
```

It will print out the text with visibles `\r\n`.